# retrieve input of collections.Counter output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

Not sure if the title is correct but.

Lets say you have a list that would look like the output from a Counter object.

```
[(-3.0, 4), (-2.0, 1), (-1.0, 1), (0.0, 1), (1.0, 1), (2.0, 1), (3.0, 4)]
```

How could I go back and get the original list, as

```
[-3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Comment: does the order matter? or can the list be sorted afterwards?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Nope. But it might do for someone else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list(Counter(dict(a)).elements())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [(-3.0, 4), (-2.0, 1), (-1.0, 1), (0.0, 1), (1.0, 1), (2.0, 1), (3.0, 4)]
>>> list(Counter(dict(a)).elements())
[-3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

So if you actually do have a `Counter`, just ask it for its `elements` directly.

Comment: Python 3.6+ though.

Comment: @JeffMercado Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: you're right! but what Jeff meant is that it doesn't preserve the order of the list. so it gives a different result in python < 3.6 where dicts are unordered. megets: `[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, -1.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0]`

Comment: well, the list can probably be sorted afterwards if order matters but order is the natural order of floats.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah I know, but I don't think it's clear whether order should be "preserved". I mean, he talks about the "original list", and who creates a Counter from a sorted list? Plus with 3.6+ it does preserve.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fair point, but that's just another reason to upgrade. :) Guido has promised that `dict` will from now on retain insertion order. OTOH, if the original list is sorted, we just need to wrap the `.elements()` call in sorted instead of `list`.

Comment: anyway I like that answer.

Comment: Me too. I was about to post it (but using `[*Counter(dict(a)).elements()]`) but I noticed that Stefan had ninja'd me. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah yes, `[*...]`. Somehow I rarely think of that. Maybe that's my subconscious rejecting it for some reason :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following nested comprehension:

```
lst = [(-3.0, 4), ..., (3.0, 4)]
[x for x, count in lst for _ in range(count)]
# [-3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
s = [(-3.0, 4), (-2.0, 1), (-1.0, 1), (0.0, 1), (1.0, 1), (2.0, 1), (3.0, 4)]
final_s = [i for b in [[a]*b for a, b in s] for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[-3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```